# FreeBSD 8.1 Apache 2.2 tries to load PHP 5.3.2 module from nonexistent debug-location

Tags: apache-http-server, php, freebsd

I am trying to get a Gallery2 installation running on my (upgraded) FreeBSD 8.1 machine. It used to be FreeBSD 6.2 and Gallery2 used to work there. My problem hopefully is not very Gallery2-related though.

What I am experiencing right now (besides other things which are - so I hope - unrelated) is that Apache (2.2.15) somewhen (when I (try to) navigate in Gallery2) tries to load a module called `pcre.so`. It seems to be looking for this module in `/usr/local/lib/php/20090626-debug`. Now that path indeed does not exist (anymore?). There is no (i.e. should not be) any debug build of php on the machine.

Here is the log entry from `/var/log/httpd-error.log`:

```
Unknown(0) : Warning - PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
        '/usr/local/lib/php/20090626-debug/pcre.so' - Cannot open
        &quot;/usr/local/lib/php/20090626-debug/pcre.so&quot;
```

I am wondering where that path comes from... There is the directory `/usr/local/lib/php/20090626/` for example but there is no `pcre.so` in it either. Also the port `devel/php5-pcre` [was removed](http://www.freshports.org/devel/php5-pcre/) (apparently because pcre is in `lang/php5` now?).

I did build PHP in debug mode first (by mistake). But I have removed and reinstalled PHP (and all extensions) and even Apache in the meantime - still the same log entry keeps popping up.

There is a second type of log entry I cannot explain (from `/var/log/httpd-error.log` again):

```
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Directive 'magic_quotes_gpc' is deprecated in PHP 5.3
        and greater in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
```

But I cannot find anything referencing/using `magic_quotes_gpc` (e.g. it is not in `/usr/local/etc/php.ini` or more precise it is commented out there).

Can anybody provide a hint why Apache could be looking for a (deprecated) module in a deprecated/non existent path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling `devel/pcre` seems to have solved the problem. See my comment to [BloodPhilia's Answer](https://superuser.com/questions/166856/freebsd-8-1-apache-2-2-tries-to-load-php-5-3-2-module-from-inexistent-debug-locat/166865#166865).

I do not know why that worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing prce, check if it works, if not, remove the php directories and then rebuild php 5:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove php5-pcre
$ rm -rf /usr/local/include/php /usr/local/lib/php /usr/local/etc/php
```

Comment: I do not have `apt-get` (on FreeBSD). But I still get the point, there is no `php5-pcre` thoug. And I have done that (more or less) already ("I have removed and reinstalled PHP (and all extensions)..."). It would probably be best if I tried to reinstall `devel/pcre` itself... Maybe that will help?

Comment: @scherand - Ah! Well it's my Ubuntu habit! ;) Sorry for that... Anyway, have you removed every single PHP directory?

Comment: Reinstalling `devel/pcre` itself won't help, the issue is with PHP's (former) `pcre.so` module, not with pcre's shared lib, which lives in `/usr/local/lib/libpcre.so`.

Comment: yes, I believe I removed everything?!? @lapo: I understand your case - but I tried nevertheless. And - surprise - the error seems to be gone. At least I did not get any of those log messages in `/var/log/httpd-error.log` for quite some time now... I cannot explain this though :(

Answer (score 0):

Extension ports don't spam the main `php.ini` file but insteaf they modify `/usr/local/etc/php/extensions.ini`, you probably must delete it from there (but that's strange, as that file doesn't use full paths, only the filename; also, this should have been taken care of during de-install of the package, maybe better check with `pkg_info|fgrep php` if you still have it, and in that case `pkg-delete` it).

Comment: There is nothing about `pcre` in `/usr/local/etc/php/extensions.ini`. But I think I managed to get rid of the error by now (see Comment on @BloodPhilia's answer). Thanks anyway!